# <script turning to <a href once published

Tags: pages, javascript, scripts

I’m trying to add an league table using this script to a WP-page:

`<script src="https://www.palloliitto.fi/torneopal/ajax/[torneopal:scoretable:competition=splfutsal1920%26amp;class=FL%26amp;group=1%26amp;key=XHGVMHFIQB]"></script>`

I’m using the ”Custom html” -block as it was suggested. It works fine once I try to preview it on the block but once I’ll publish or preview the page, script just shows up as a hyperlink. When I inspect the hyperlink I found out that it had turned from 'script to a href.

Any ideas how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your caching plugins are preventing the script from loading.
Your site may also be http and not https, hence the reason why https script cannot load. Try changing the script to http:

```
<script src="http://www.palloliitto.fi/torneopal/ajax/[torneopal:scoretable:competition=splfutsal1920%26amp;class=FL%26amp;group=1%26amp;key=XHGVMHFIQB]"></script>
```

If that doesn't help, send us a link to the page where you inserted it.

Comment: Unfortunately changing it to http didn’t help. Here’s the link to the page https://www.pp70futsal.fi/testing-a-script It should look something like a table on this page https://www.fckemi.fi/miehet-futsal-liiga/ (scroll down just before the list of games to be played)

Comment: It looks like you are adding the script in the Visual tab and not the Text tab of WordPress. If you are using Gutenburg editor you can use the block called **Custom HTML**

Comment: I have been using Custom html -block in Gutenberg visual editor

Comment: If you switch to a different theme. Does that help? What about if you insert it inside of the sidebar into an HTML widget?